Automatically update hibernate persistence unit on IntelliJ IDEA 2024
In former versions of IntelliJ IDEA, I was able to both automatically update the hibernate persistence unit (hibernate.cfg.xml) and generate the JPA Entities using the 'Generate persistence mapping' option. This option has been replaced by 'JPA Entities from DB' in IntelliJ IDEA 2024 but, when using it, only the entities are generated, but no updating of the persistence unit is done.
Although I can manually update the unit, I would like to know if there is some way to reproduce the former behaviour of the 'Generate persistence mapping' option, automatically updating the unit.

The new action came from JPA Buddy plugin. It still has no perfect integration with IDEA's other features, but we keep working on it. There is a ticket for the case you described - IDEA-352572. The former behavior is not available anymore and we are not going to return it back.
